# Book with worms that burrow through material

Tags: story-identification

In the episode [The Aenar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Aenar_(episode)) of Star Trek Enterprise there are some worms that burrow through the ceiling.  This reminded me of reading a story with a similar creatures.  I do recollect also it might not be ice they burrow through but stone/lava.  But they were definitely small and dangerous. (why it reminded me)

[image]

I will own this book and I do wonder if it was a Piers Anthony story? as he has drastically changing themes through them.

I realise this is very little information and I am trying to remember more.

Comment: As you say, it's very little information. Do you at least remember approximately when you read it?

Comment: Piers Anthony's Xanth books have recurring infestations of [wiggles](http://xanth.wikia.com/wiki/Wiggle), small creatures that zap through any material and have to be exterminated when they swarm - could that be what you're thinking of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Piers Anthony You are thinking of the wiggles. These are wormlike creatures that burrow through anything in their path. That includes stone and earth, but also anything else unlucky enough to be in their way.

The wiggles appear in several books, but their main appearance is in [Dragon on a Pedestal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_on_a_Pedestal) where the protagonists band together to fight a huge swarm of wiggles that threatens to destroy everything in their path.

Comment: "Wiggles" also occur naturally in Australia.  My favorite is Jeff.

Comment: Gonna dig this out I defiantly have it and read it awhile ago so might be it.

Comment: @Dreamwalker do you want me to edit a few quotes into the answer in case they trigger memories?